# Automatically restore connection to the main queue when server is up again

Tags: java, jms, apache-camel, ibm-mq

I have a master MQ and a slave MQ. If the master MQ goes down, can I send the messages through the slave MQ using a message driven bean ? Also after my master MQ is up again can I reconnect the line automatically without restarting the JVM ?

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is please? You've basically described the high availability feature of MQ

Comment: I just want to know if i can automatically restore the master MQ through message driven bean once it is up. I have two MQ's. one is master and the other one is slave. so whenever master goes down through failover i will send my messages through slave. My question is once the master MQ is up can i automatically restore and send messages through master mq through message driven bean

Comment: Better explanation and English upgrade (question marks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your HA (high-availability) Active/Passive or Active/Active?  The standard HA is Active/Passive, so I will answer your question under that scenario.

When your MQ system is normally running - the active queue manager (master) is running (up) and the passive queue manager (slave) is stopped (down).  If the the active queue manager (master) has a problem and is stopped then the passive queue manager (slave) is started.

At some point in the future when the problem with the master queue manager is fixed, the passive queue manager (slave) is stopped and the master queue manager is started.

If you are using reconnect in your application, when the slave queue manager is stopped, your application will be disconnected and when the master queue manager is started, your application will connect to it.

For HA Active/Passive, you can only ever have 1 queue manager running at a time (or none). You never have both the master and slave running at the same time.